# Simple regex expression advice

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
"Price: $       $110.49Foil Sale!14 in stock"
```

I want to get that 14 in the middle, how can I do it with regex?

EDIT:
Sometimes the string comes like this:

```
Price: $     
                                        3 in stock
```

in this case i would only need the 3

ive tried this: `[/[^$][0-9]\z{1,3}/]` but it didnt work, im not good at all with regular expressions

Comment: any other patterns? are the strings always the same format?

Comment: What language are you using? Can you show us 10 strings, instead of just one?

Comment: edited with more ifno

Comment: A) "regex" has a slew of meanings/definitions. B) A "regex" may not be the right approach. Tell us which tool(s) you want to/can use instead and which OS you'll be running on.

Answer (score 3):

If the text : "in stock" is fixed you can simply get the 14 with :

```
(\d+) in stock
```

In the first capturing group you will find the number 14

If you want to match only yhe number 14, you can use a look ahead expression :

```
(\d+)(?= in stock)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do anything with just " xx in stock"
You might need to know what it is.

```
 #  ^(.*?)(\d*)\s*in\s+stock\s*$

 ^ 
 (                            # (1 start)
      # what is in stock 
      .*? 
 )                            # (1 end)
 (                            # (2 start)
      # how many 
      \d* 
 )                            # (2 end)
 \s* in \s+ stock \s* 
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression '^.*(14).*$'  (without the quotes - replace by '$1') is the simplest way, as long as there is only one occurence of 14 in your whole string.

If you have multiple occurences, it gets a little more complex.